# Most questions under maritime-law are probably mistagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

[maritime-law](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maritime-law) is about "laws governing private maritime disputes [...]  Not to be confused with the Law of the Sea [...]". Yet most questions here tagged with maritime-law are about some *country* doing something like firing warning shots at vessels, which don't strike me as private disputes.

I've created [maritime-security](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maritime-security) which [seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maritime_security) to me more broadly/correctly covers such issues, even if it's been called a 'buzzword' by some.

> The US Naval Operations Concept from 2006 for example listed “ensuring the freedom of navigation, the flow of commerce and the protection of ocean resources, as well as securing the maritime domain from nation-state threats, terrorism, drug trafficking and other forms of transnational crime, piracy, environmental destruction and illegal seaborne immigration” as the goal of maritime security.

(N.B. [piracy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/piracy) did exist, with 3 Qs, while there are 19 tagged as maritime-law, after I retagged one recent Q.)

Also [law-of-the-sea](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law-of-the-sea) didn't even exist. To quote NOAA on the latter:

> The law of the sea is a body of customs, treaties, and international agreements by which governments maintain order, productivity, and peaceful relations on the sea.

Most questions here under the maritime-law tag probably rather belong to one or both of these other tags. Your thoughts on this?

Comment: I'd be inclined to edit `maritime-law` to encompass everything it's currently being used for, rather than try to make a distinction that most people using the tag on a question won't understand.

Comment: [tag:maritime-and-sea-law] maybe as an umbrella term?